# Comparison and creating new column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

**Table A**

```
    > - Product#|Customer|state|Type   
      Glasses |mr. Xyz | MN |Instore    
      Glasses |mr. abc | MN |Instore    
  perishables|mr. abc12| TN |Instore 
 N-perishables|mr. abc122| GN |Instore
```

**Table B**

```
> - Product#|Name|state|Type   
  Glasses |mr. fff | MN |online    
  Glasses |mr. abc | MN |online    
perishables|mr. abc12 | TN |online 
 Non-perishables|mr. abc122 | GN |online

    `
```

Trying to create new column and then do comparing?
Condition, if the type is **in-store they are never new customer**, if they are online they could be new customer only if their record do not exist in In-store Type.

o/p

```
Type|customer| New Customer?
Instore|mr. Xyz  |No
Instore|mr. abc  |No
Instore|mr. abc12|No
Instore|mr. abc122|No
Online| mr.fff    |Yes -"as it's record is not available  in-store type, hence it will be labelled as new customer"
```

Query tried:

```
select 
       `Customer`, 
    CASE
    WHEN `customer` in (select `Customer` from `Table B`)  THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'NO'
END AS 'new customer'
FROM Table A`
```

Please give me optimized query, as its huge data in millions.

Comment: @danblack any clue on this ? this is the complete question  with desired o/p and i/p tables.

Comment: Please add the table definitions, index included, and tag your MySQL server version.

Comment: Billions of customers?  What planet are you living on?  Is there a table with one row per Customer?

Comment: @McNets, I dont understand what kinds of table definition you are looking for ? and I have index code too added in he code, I add index by Product#. Its 8.0 version. Please give me a query for desired o/p

Comment: @RickJames, yes we have millions of transactions everyday world wide. Please provide the query.

Answer (score 0):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` is often an inefficient way to design a query.  There are two alternatives below.  Also, your `IN` was asking to fetch the entire array; this is probably causing terrible performance.  You only need to check for the "existence" of one `customer`.

Note that each formulation checks for one "customer" in `Table B` and does not fetch the entire table (as is done with your `IN ( SELECT ... )`).

Two approaches:

```
SELECT  Customer,
        IF(b.customer IS NOT NULL, 'Yes', 'No') AS "new customer"
    FROM  `Table A` AS a
    LEFT JOIN  `Table B` AS b USING(customer);

SELECT  Customer,
        IF(EXISTS (
                SELECT  1
                    FROM  `Table B`
                    WHERE  customer = a.customer ) , 'Yes', 'No'
          ) AS "new customer"
    FROM  `Table A` AS a;
```

`LEFT` implies that the row may be missing from `Table B`.  This is exactly what you want in order to produce "No".

`EXISTS` is a "semi-join".  It stops when it finds success; this can be handy if there could be multiple matching rows (which is not your case).